# JFrame not opening in Eclipse Mac

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to run a simple Swing program through Eclipse in my Mac. The application runs but i am not able to see the UI appearing.

I am on Mac Mojave and Eclipse Version: Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)

This is working fine if i am running the program through command line

Below is my code

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import org.saurav.simpletests.io.HttpClientTester;

public class HelloWorldSwing {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        JFrame  frame  = new JFrame("Swing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username");
        frame.getContentPane().add(usernameLabel);

        JTextField userText = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(userText);


        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("password");
        frame.getContentPane().add(passwordLabel);

        JTextField passwordText = new JTextField();
        frame.getContentPane().add(passwordText);

        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String userName = userText.getText();

            String password = passwordText.getText();

            HttpClientTester httpClientTester = new HttpClientTester();
            httpClientTester.executeHttp(Constants.URL, userName, password);
        });
        frame.setSize(100,100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Best Regards, Saurav"* Don't include 'sig. noise' in questions or answers.

Comment: The layout of the ContentPane of a JFrame is by default BorderLayout. You are adding one component over the other to its center.

Comment: Don't know the reason for down voting..it will be helpful if i am told the reason

Answer (score 3):

See the comments in the following MCVE:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class HelloWorldSwing {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        JFrame  frame  = new JFrame("Swing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        /*
         * JFrame (content pane) uses BorderLayout as default.
         * getContentPane().add(c) adds c to BorderLayout.CENTER location which
         * can hold only one component, so each add() overwrite the previous one.
         * One solution is to use another layout manager like FlowLayout
         */
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username");
        frame.getContentPane().add(usernameLabel);

        JTextField userText = new JTextField(10); //set text field size
        frame.getContentPane().add(userText);

        JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("password");
        frame.getContentPane().add(passwordLabel);

        JTextField passwordText = new JTextField(10); //set text field size
        frame.getContentPane().add(passwordText);

        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        button.addActionListener(e -> {});//this is not needed to demonstrate the problem
        //frame.setSize(100,100); do not set size. Let pack set the size 
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: By mistake it got down voted...please edit the answer a bit so that i can revert the down vote

Comment: actually...problem was something else...please check my answer

Comment: "please edit the answer a bit so that i can revert the down vote" - I edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

A `setSize` call followed by a `pack` call doesn't make much sense. What [pack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack()) does:

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize method. [...]

Either don't `pack` if you strictly want the size from your call to setSize, or don't `setSize` and have suitable preferred sizes (and if neccessary minimum sizes) for the components in your window.

Comment: Before adding your first component insert this line: frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout()); Also add columns to your JTextField constructors: JTextField userText = new JTextField(10);

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to class loading.

I had some classes which were using SWT dependencies which were in the classpath. It seems SWT and Swing has some problem to coexist.

Once i removed the SWT dependencies , Frame appeared in the screen.